# Unable to locate elements through selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

**HTML Code**

```
<div id="all_transactions_for_account">
<table class="table table-condensed table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th>Deposit</th>
        <th>Withdrawal</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
        <td>2012-09-06</td>
        <td>ONLINE TRANSFER REF #UKKSDRQG6L</td>
        <td>984.3</td>
        <td></td>
        </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2012-09-05</td>
        <td>OFFICE SUPPLY</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>50</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2012-09-01</td>
        <td>ONLINE TRANSFER REF #UKKSDRQG6L</td>
        <td>1000</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**Java code**

```
public class Sample {

    @Test
    public void sampleMethod() throws InterruptedException
    {
        WebDriver driver;
        driver= new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();

        driver.get("http://zero.webappsecurity.com/login.html");

        driver.findElement(By.id("user_login")).sendKeys("username");
        driver.findElement(By.id("user_password")).sendKeys("password");
        driver.findElement(By.name("submit")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.linkText("Savings")).click();
        WebElement e =driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='all_transactions_for_account']/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]"));
        System.out.println(e.getText());
    }

}
```

Not only that single element,I not able to find any element in this page. Refer to screen

[image]

So please help me I spent more than 2 day but i can't find the solution.

Comment: You might wanna add the error message that you are getting.

Comment: Below is the error gorg.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":".//*[@id='all_transactions_for_account']/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]"}

Answer (score 0):

Here are some changes what you need to do:

To work with Selenium 3.4.0 along with latest gecko driver 0.16 & Mozila Firefox 53.0, you need to download the gecko driver and save it. Mention the absolute location of gecko driver in `System.setProperty`

Finally your code will look like:

```
@Test
public void sampleMethod() 
{
    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\geckodriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver= new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.get("http://zero.webappsecurity.com/login.html");
    driver.findElement(By.id("user_login")).sendKeys("username");
    driver.findElement(By.id("user_password")).sendKeys("password");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='submit']")).click();        
}
```

Let me know if this helps you.

Comment: I 'am using Firefox 31.0 and for this version gecko driver is not necessary.I also tried with latest FF and gecko drive but there is no luck.So please help me, i have mentioned even username and password as well in code, can you give a try ?

Comment: @user3091748 Incase your are using Firefox 31.0, you can simply omit the line `System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\geckodriver.exe");` Rest of the code should work for you? Please update the status.

Comment: No it is not working, I will try again in new machine and i will update